# MQTT Connection Lost : Connection issues when combining HTTP and MQTT calls in a loop

Tags: c, https, embedded, mqtt, arduino-esp8266

I am using The HTTP part to make a URL call, and the MQTT part allows to publish a message to a specified topic. BUT Experiencing connection issues when combining HTTP and MQTT calls in a loop,MQTT Connection Lost repeatedly.
If I Remove HTTP Call then MQTT work smoothly without connection Lost.

Module : ESP8266 Wi-Fi 12E
IDE : Ardunio
Please Find Below Code

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

const char* ssid = "OOB SMARTHOME";
const char* password = "OOB123456";

const char* serverUrl = "http://example.com/api";  // Replace with your server URL

const char* mqtt_server = "mqtt_broker_IP";
const char* mqtt_username = "mqtt_username";
const char* mqtt_password = "mqtt_password";

WiFiClient wifiClient;
PubSubClient mqttClient(wifiClient);

const short int   BUILTIN_LED1 = 2; //GPIO2 esp8266

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  pinMode(BUILTIN_LED1, OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED1, HIGH); //LED OFF
    
  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");

  // Connect to MQTT broker
  mqttClient.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  while (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Connecting to MQTT...");
    if (mqttClient.connect("ESP8266lient123", mqtt_username, mqtt_password)) {
      Serial.println("Connected to MQTT");
      mqttClient.publish("123456789PB", "HELLO");
     mqttClient.subscribe("123456789SB");
    } else {
      Serial.print("Failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(mqttClient.state());
      Serial.println(" Trying again in 5 seconds...");
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void reconnectMQTT() {
  while (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Reconnecting to MQTT...");
    if (mqttClient.connect("ESP8266Client", mqtt_username, mqtt_password)) {
      Serial.println("Reconnected to MQTT");
    } else {
      Serial.print("Failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(mqttClient.state());
      Serial.println(" Trying again in 5 seconds...");
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  // Your other non-blocking loop code can go here

  // Send data using HTTP
  sendHTTPData("81X24TJJB4SCENEAQ");  // Replace with your actual data payload

  // Publish to MQTT
  publishMQTT("Your MQTT payload");  // Replace with your actual MQTT payload

   if (!mqttClient.connected()) 
                    {
                      reconnectMQTT();  
                      digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED1, HIGH); //LED OFF
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED1, LOW); //LED OFF
                      mqttClient.loop();
                    }

  delay(5000);  // Adjust the delay as needed
}

void sendHTTPData(const String& data) {
  HTTPClient http;

  // Specify the server and resource
  http.begin(wifiClient, serverUrl);  // Use ::begin(WiFiClient, url)

  // Add headers if needed
  // http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

  // Construct the POST request with data
  int httpCode = http.POST(data);

  // Check the HTTP response
  if (httpCode > 0) {
    Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
    Serial.println(httpCode);
    String payload = http.getString();
    Serial.println("HTTP Response payload: " + payload);
  } else {
    Serial.println("HTTP request failed");
  }

  // Close the connection
  http.end();
}

void publishMQTT(const String& payload) {
  // Publish to MQTT
  if (mqttClient.connected()) {
    mqttClient.publish("123456789PB", payload.c_str());
    Serial.println("Published to MQTT: " + payload);
  }
}
```

I want Solution for this issue with code functionalities or any suggestion regarding this problem.

Comment: you use the same WiFiClient object for both.

Comment: even with different WiFiCilent same issue , I tried with Different WiFiCilent too

Comment: What do the MQTT broker logs show as the reason for the connection being dropped? And how big is the HTTP Payload (both outbound and the response)

Comment: shows the version with two WiFiClient objects. this one can't work

Comment: Thank You for your reply I am trying with POST method instead of GET method

Answer (score 0):

You are using delay(5000) in your loop, this can affect the MQTT and HTTP calls, consider using the millis() function instead of delay. You can check the inbuild example:blinkwithoutdelay for this.

On a more broader solution, using RTOS on an ESP32 device will give you a better performance

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are facing issues with combining HTTP and MQTT calls in a loop, leading to repeated MQTT connection losses. This issue might be related to the blocking nature of HTTP requests and the need for non-blocking operations in an ESP8266 environment.

Here are a few suggestions to address this problem:

**Use Non-Blocking HTTP Requests:**

- Consider using non-blocking HTTP requests to avoid blocking the loop
  for an extended period.
- You can use libraries like [ESPAsyncHTTPClient](https://github.com/hatlabs/ESPAsyncHTTPClient) for asynchronous HTTP
  requests.

**Separate HTTP and MQTT Handling:**

- Move the HTTP and MQTT logic into separate functions.
- In the loop, check for the conditions to perform either HTTP or MQTT
  operations based on timing or other criteria.

**Increase Loop Delay:**

- Increase the delay in the loop to allow both HTTP and MQTT operations
  to complete without causing connection issues.
- Experiment with different delay values to find a balance between
  responsiveness and stability.

Here's a modified example incorporating these suggestions:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESPAsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncHTTPClient.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

// ... (other definitions)

AsyncHTTPClient http;
unsigned long lastHTTPMillis = 0;

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  // Your other non-blocking loop code can go here

  // Send data using HTTP every 10 seconds
  if (currentMillis - lastHTTPMillis > 10000) {
    sendHTTPData("81X24TJJB4SCENEAQ");
    lastHTTPMillis = currentMillis;
  }

  // Publish to MQTT
  publishMQTT("Your MQTT payload");

  if (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    reconnectMQTT();
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED1, HIGH); // LED OFF
  } else {
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED1, LOW); // LED ON
    mqttClient.loop();
  }

  delay(100);  // Adjust the delay as needed
}
```

Please note that this is a basic example, and you may need to adjust the delay and timing based on your specific requirements. Additionally, consider using more advanced libraries like **ESPAsyncHTTPClient** for improved non-blocking HTTP operations.